# Always prompt user to select an account on application start

Tags: c#, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the code from the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet) to authenticate user on application start.

```
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
    );
}

var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
});
```

Everything works fine except that I want to force the Select Account screen to show every time (now it only shows the first time, and then after that the user is remembered) because the application is supposed to allow different users to log in.

Looks like that I'm supposed to set the [`prompt`](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#prompt) request parameter to  `select_account`, but I don't know how am I supposed to do this, `AuthorizeAsync` method doesn't accept any additional arguments.

Comment: If you want to allow different users to log in, I'd consider adding a logout flow instead of forcing the user to log in to the app every single time it is opened. That's not very user-friendly

Comment: The OP already has the correct solution. He needs to set `prompt=select_account` using the c# library. logging out is not appropriate

Comment: yeah, I just don't know how to do that :D

Comment: @N0ug4t i might actually consider implementing something like that in the future, now that you've mentioned it, but i don't want that right know

Comment: I'm a huge anti-fan of libraries that make simple stuff complicated. It might be worth simply calling the OAuth endpoints directly. Personally I find that simpler and more robust.

Comment: "Given the security implications of getting the implementation correct, we strongly encourage you to use OAuth 2.0 libraries when interacting with Google's OAuth 2.0 endpoints. It is a best practice to use well-debugged code provided by others, and it will help you protect yourself and your users. For more information, see [Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#libraries)." ---- That's basically how I ended up here :) If I don't find any other way, I guess that I will have to implement that myself.

Comment: I can only relate to my own experiences of wrangling Google OAuth for the first time. I tried using the libraries (Java and JS) as the obvious path of least resistance and was constantly tripping over leaky abstractions, version hell and out of date documentation. It was only when I started calling the endpoints directly that things started to work robustly and in a way that was sympathetic to my specific use cases. 

Props to @chris for responding so quickly with a PR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that this is currently not possible to do in a simple way.

I've filed a bug to fix this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1322

Comment: Cool, I see that you've closed the issue. I'm now waiting for the next release?

Comment: v1.37.0 with this fix is now released.

Comment: You need to use the overload of `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` that takes a `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer`. See here for how to config it: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/3df8be701a96e7cbe79e358323b92be285432aa5/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs#L97