# Prompt user to always select Google account

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, google-oauth

I'm working on a .NET desktop app that needs interaction with Youtube APIs.
I'm following the first sample at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

My code runs fine, but I want to force the user to select the right Google account every time the application starts.

I've tried the following modification of the above sample:

```
    UserCredential credential;
    using (var stream = new FileStream("Assets\\client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecretsStream = stream,
                Prompt = "select_account" // <-- This line does nothing...
            },
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None
            );
    }
```

To my understanding, based on this old [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100139/always-prompt-user-to-select-an-account-on-application-start), adding the `Prompt = "select_account"` parameter should do the trick but in reality it doesn't work as expected.

**Infact it appears that the credentials are somewhat cached and the desired prompt never appears.**

I've even tried to recompile the code in this way:

```
            //omissis...
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets(), // <- no reference to the stream!
                Prompt = "select_account"
            },
```

and with my big surprise the app still work without any reference to the client_secret.json stream! Authentication is skipped completely after the user successfully logs in for the first time

Comment: You probably want to look into something like the OAuth Token lifetime

Comment: Sorry I cannot see how this can be useful in my case. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: The point of OAuth (and most auth systems) is that you don't have to keep asking the user to login *every* time, and so they cache an access token (not the password).  OAuth in particular has both an Auth token and a Refresh token. To force a re-login, you must time-out the Auth token.

Comment: Ok @Immersive I see your point but still I cannot explain why my code (the first snippet) won't work even if I set the prompt parameter on "select_account"...

Comment: My guess is that the result of the prompt is cached.  But it's really outside of my skillset.